# TypeScript: How to get and use types of a class method with multiple declarations

Tags: typescript

Can't explain it better than what's in the title, so here's an example:

```
declare class myClass {
  myMethod(num: number): number; // declaration 1
  myMethod(str: string, num: number): number; // declaration 2
}

let func1: myClass['myMethod'] = (num: number) => 0;

let func2: myClass['myMethod'] = (str: string, num: number) => 0;
```

The above doesn't compile, outputting the following errors:

```
error TS2322: Type '(num: number) => number' is not assignable to type '{ (num: number): number; (str: string, num: number): number; }'.
  Types of parameters 'num' and 'str' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
error TS2322: Type '(str: string, num: number) => number' is not assignable to type '{ (num: number): number; (str: string, num: number): number; }'.
```

If I comment out either of:

- declaration 1 and func1 or
- declaration 2 and func2,

compilation is successful.

Multiple declarations of the same method is something that happens quite often in declaration files of some open source packages, e.g. `aws-sdk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple function or method declarations describe [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).  Overloaded functions or methods have one or more *call signatures* which are part of the declaration of the type.  You can represent this set of call signatures either as repeated function/method/callable signatures in an interface/class/scope, or as the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of all the call signatures.  An overloaded function must be callable in *each* of the ways described by the call signatures.

When you implement an overloaded function or method, you use a single *implementation signature* which is not seen from the outside... it's an implementation detail of the function.  But the implementation signature needs to be able to handle all the call signatures.  If it can't, you have a problem.

I'll rewrite your code as a single overloaded function interface `MyMethod`:

```
interface MyMethod {
  (num: number): number; // declaration 1
  (str: string, num: number): number; // declaration 2
}

let func1: MyMethod = (num: number) => 0; // error
let func2: MyMethod = (str: string, num: number) => 0; // error
```

That's basically the same as your code, and it has the same problem.  `func1` is *not* a valid `MyMethod`.  You can only call `func1(123)`, but you can't call `func1("abc",123)`.  But a `MyMethod` has to support both calls.  Similarly, `func2` only supports the second call signature and not the first.

Now consider this:

```
let funcBoth: MyMethod = (strOrNum: string | number, num?: number) => 0; // okay
```

This compiles just fine.  That's because the implementation signature of `funcBoth` can support being called like `funcBoth(123)`  *and* like `funcBoth("abc", 123)`:

```
funcBoth(123); // okay
funcBoth("abc", 123); // okay
```

Now, the implementation signature would also have supported being called like `funcBoth(123, 456)`, but the annotation of `funcBoth` as `MyMethod` does not let you do that:

```
funcBoth(123, 456); // error! bad first argument
```

So the implementation signature is hidden from callers, and so inside your function implementation you can safely rely on the fact that callers will not pass in unexpected parameters.

---

If you want the behavior of calling `func1` or `func2` depending on how `funcBoth` is called, you have to do the dispatching yourself by checking arguments:

```
let f1 = (num: number) => 0; 
let f2 = (str: string, num: number) => 0; 

let f12: MyMethod = (strOrNum: string | number, num?: number) =>
  typeof strOrNum === "number" ? f1(strOrNum) : f2(strOrNum, num!);
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE9UTACwPYAmyA3gFDLIAUIArgLYBcytdARtAJRMvtQDcyAPSDkBCAgA2cKHDDA8IZAEZyVAM5goTDVFABzADTN63ery7G20AcNHipMuQuQAmUgF9SpCdmQwaIAhKTBhYuITIALxULKZWUBxRAHzIAAw2ItBQeFDevv6BLiGY2PhE0ZQ62pr6RrGW5slpGchZOV4+YH4BCABCeLjFYWVR6poA8lAAcibIOvrIAD4N0HX0APxxjZEp6aQFfQM4lEouAMwcLXgA1nDo+z39uJQARHCsCC9GpxdXt-cHJ7HH5GAAsAFYAGyXISZKDZKAAQmQrDgRBgwCgGmQ0j09Ag4A6+SUo2osx4nCa6WQeS6MBcpKqcxqIEMli2lJ2zRptL8pyGpQiFR0kxmjGZulZSxWUDWdE2MsSO1UYHQAAcIHgYBLRfQopFoi8KVAXsh1nzKhNpvREkx6ZaoLq6HLEZdSEA)

Comment: Amazing answer. Thanks.